# Book, alien uses mindcontrol machine to manipulate a mob of humans

Tags: story-identification

I read this around 1981, in the US, in English, in paperback most likely.  I feel like it dated to the 50, 60s or early 70s at the latest.  The only scene I remember is:

A man (the protagonist, I believe) watches an alien creature, who I think was somewhat caterpillar-like, use a machine to manipulate a mob/crowd of humans.  I think the mob chased or attacked one or more scientists.  This was only one small part of the story (a couple of pages), not the main idea of the book.

I associate the memory of this with *The War Against the Rull* by A.E. Van Vogt, but summaries I've read of it don't sound familiar at all.  Possibly I bought the two books from a used bookstore at the same time, because my copy of *The War Against the Rull*, which I can't find right now, was an old used paperback.

I remember thinking at the time that the alien creatures were possibly the/an inspiration for the 'Hiver' species from the *Traveler* roleplaying game, who were known for their prowess with psychology and manipulation.